# Create uniques couple of value and count their occurence with same value in other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new in SQL world, don't be too rude with me...

I have a simple SQL table for an only game with :

- ServerName
- PlayerName

I want to group all players by pair Player_1, Player_2 and count how many times they logged on the same server.

For example with the table :

```
ServerName | PlayerName
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    S1     |    a 
    S3     |    a 
    S1     |    b
    S3     |    c 
    S4     |    b
    S4     |    a
```

I want to be able to produce :

```
a b 2
a c 1
b c 0
```

.. and so for all unique couple (Player_1, Player_2)

I tryed some technique with join on the table with itself and the distinct key but nothing as I want.

I'm not sure to clearly understand the behavior of 'Order By' function.

I'm working on postgresql.

Comment: Don't use tags of DBMS not related to the question. That won't give your question more attention, at least not positive one.

Comment: Note: you are not using the logintime in your logic. Maybe it is not needed? (it is relatively worthless without a logouttime, anyway)

Comment: Thanks for the advise @stickybit, I'll try to be a better user int the future !
And for the loginTime it just for another purpose... Not sure if I must precise it in that case or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve it with joining the table to itself, let's assume the table is called `game`

```
SELECT g1.playername,g2.playername,COUNT(1) games
FROM game g1
JOIN game g2
   ON g1.servername = g2.servername
   AND g1.playername < g2.playername
GROUP BY g1.playername,g2.playername
ORDER BY g1.playername,g2.playername
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you ! 
Just a quick question, is it possible to have couple of playername with 0 server in common ? Not that is very useful in my case but I'm curious

Comment: This doesn't produce zero counts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want zeros then cross join all players and left join to aggregate:

```
select p1.playername, p2.playername,
       count(t2.servername)
from players p1 join
     players p2
     on p1.playername < p2.playername left join
     games g1
     on g1.playername = p1.playername left join
     games g2
     on g2.playername = p2.playername and
        g2.servername = g1.servername
group by p1.playername, p2.playername;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this did not pass my tests... When I look the result, the count was way too big (ex: 32 instead of 2) but all the 0 values were correct...